# Kafka server failed to start - java.io.IOException: Map failed

Tags: server, out-of-memory, apache-kafka, ioexception

I am not able to start Kafka Server because of the error below.

```
java.io.IOException: Map failed
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:940)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.<init>(AbstractIndex.scala:61)
    at kafka.log.TimeIndex.<init>(TimeIndex.scala:55)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.<init>(LogSegment.scala:73)
    at kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:267)
    at kafka.log.Log.<init>(Log.scala:116)
    at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$createLog$1.apply(LogManager.scala:365)
    at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$createLog$1.apply(LogManager.scala:361)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.createLog(LogManager.scala:361)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$getOrCreateReplica$1.apply(Partition.scala:109)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$getOrCreateReplica$1.apply(Partition.scala:106)
    at kafka.utils.Pool.getAndMaybePut(Pool.scala:70)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition.getOrCreateReplica(Partition.scala:105)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Partition.scala:166)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Partition.scala:166)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$4.apply(Partition.scala:166)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$4.apply(Partition.scala:160)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:213)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inWriteLock(CoreUtils.scala:221)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition.makeLeader(Partition.scala:160)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$makeLeaders$4.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:754)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$makeLeaders$4.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:753)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.makeLeaders(ReplicaManager.scala:753)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.becomeLeaderOrFollower(ReplicaManager.scala:698)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleLeaderAndIsrRequest(KafkaApis.scala:148)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:84)
    at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:937)
    ... 34 more
```

Tried the below options . but of no use . please help

Upgraded OS from 32 to 64 Bit.
Increased java heap size to 1 GB.
Uninstalled and installed Apache Kafka

Comment: What is your kafka version?

Comment: JVM is the problem. I was using JVM 32 Bit and upgrading to 64 Bit solves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Ok that's cool. You should post the answer then! It might be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Upgrading the JVM to 64 bit resolved the issue

Answer (score 16):

When this doesn't resolve the problem you could try to increase vm.max_map_count. The default value is 65536 (check this with `sysctl vm.max_map_count`)

With `cat /proc/[kafka-pid]/maps | wc -l` you can see how many maps are used.

Increase the setting with :

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Comment: Worked for us, After increasing max memory-map count we are not facing issue anymore.

Comment: Is there a setting for windows?

Answer (score 7):

This helped me : Changing KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx256M -Xms256M" (Originally 512m)

change this to : kafka-server-start script

Thanks !

Comment: Surprisingly, DECREASING memory fixed my issue as well.

Comment: This worked on my windows setup.

Answer (score 2):

this helped me: 
change :
`export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx512M -Xms512M"`
(originally 1G)

in kafka-server-start script

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Windows, Kafka takes some memory during the process. So We need to increase the heap to prevent throttling the performance of the application. This can be achieved graphically through JAVA Control Panel.

[image]

Inside Runtime Parameters, you can change the size of the memory allocated by JVM:

- -Xmx512m that assigns 512MB,
- -Xmx1024m that assigns 1GB,
- -Xmx2048m that assigns 2GB,
- -Xmx3072m that assigns 3GB memory and so on.

[image]